# recieving notifications from parse server on windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, parse-platform

I'm building a windows phone application connected with parse server I want know could I recieve push notifications from the server (I send the notification from the server but I don't recieve it and the connection is fine with the server because I can send objects and the server recieve them perfectly). I made many reseaches I found a piece of code but I didn't know where to put it so I put it on a button click like this:

```
private async void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var installation = ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation;
            installation.AddUniqueToList("channels", "Giants");
            await installation.SaveAsync();
            MessageBox.Show("Done ! ");
            ParsePush.ToastNotificationReceived += ParsePushOnToastNotificationReceived;
            await ParseAnalytics.TrackAppOpenedAsync();
            MessageBox.Show("Done ! ");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    void ParsePushOnToastNotificationReceived(object sender, NotificationEventArgs notificationEventArgs)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            // do anything
            MessageBox.Show("got notification");
        });
    }
```